# Issue in mysql Join query

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

I am developing a social website.I have an option called `alerts` which shows pending friend requests and unread messages.My query is following:

```sql
SELECT
  sk_friends.frndship_from_user_id,
  sk_messages.msg_from_user_id,
  sk_messages.msg_text,
  sk_messages.msg_date 
FROM
  sk_friends INNER JOIN sk_messages
WHERE 
  sk_messages.msg_to_user_id = '$user_id'
  AND sk_friends.frndship_to_user_id ='$user_id'  
  AND sk_friends.frndship_status = 'pending'
  AND sk_messages.msg_status='unread'
ORDER BY 
  sk_friends.fndship_date ASC,
  sk_messages.msg_date ASC;
```

- sk_friends and ak_messages are tables.
- msg_from_user_id is the id of sender
- frndship_from_user_id is the id of the user who sends the request
- $user_id is the id of the login user

Each row data is appearing twice. I dont know why does it happen.

Comment: Can you make a small [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) and explain?

Comment: you have missed ON statement in join query. check http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html to apply inner join.

Comment: Use "ON" in place of "WHERE" in the JOIN-segment of your query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your inner join does not have an ON clause. Try adding one, that should remove  double results.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT 
    sf.frndship_from_user_id,
    sm.msg_from_user_id,
    sm.msg_text,sm.msg_date 
FROM 
    sk_friends sf ,
    sk_messages sm 
WHERE 
    sm.msg_to_user_id = sf.frndship_to_user_id AND
    sm.msg_to_user_id = '$user_id'  AND     
    sf.frndship_status = 'pending' AND 
    sm.msg_status='unread' 
ORDER BY 
    sf.fndship_date ASC,sm.msg_date ASC;
```